# Just installed Ubuntu on my MacBook pro. Now my screen randomly goes black during use

Tags: screen, macbook

Just installed Ubuntu on my MacBook pro (15 inch Mid 2010) today and I am running into an issue where my screen will just go black and it almost seems like the computer shuts down suddenly.  The backlit keyboard is still on so I know the computer isn't off but everything else seems unresponsive.  I don't know what the cause of this is. I have checked the heat sensors and they all seem ok and I cannot find any consistency in what may trigger this happening.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what version do you have 12.04, 14.04?

Comment: I believe I installed 14.04

Comment: Once the screen has turned black can you bring up a virtual terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+F1? I'm wondering if it its the system crashing or the display server.

Comment: I tried to do that and nothing happened.  Would the keyboard still be lit up if the system crashed?